# Xamarin Forms iOS: Why renderer is a native view wrapping the native view of the control?

Tags: xamarin.forms

On iOS, inspecting the hierarchy, I can see that the ButtonRenderer is a native UIView which has as subview the UIButton.

Why is it necessary to have the renderer wrapping the UIButton? 
Why couldn't just Xamarin Forms created and used the UIButton, why is the renderer native view necessary?

Comment: Because their framework is not the same.Xamarin.Forms can not use UIbutton directly,so need ButtonRenderer to invoke.

In **Xamarin Forms**, is .Net Framwork,

and Button's Inheritance relationships is 

*Object->BindableObject->Element->VisualElement->View->Button*,

In **IOS Native**,is CocoTouch Framework,

and UIButton's Inheritance relationships is 

*NSObject->UIResponder ->UIView-> UIControl -> UIButton*

if want to use ButtonRender ,you can refer to [this document]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/renderers

Comment: @johnheaven Thanks but it does not answer my question. You only said "Xamarin.Forms can not use UIbutton directly". Why can't it use it directly? That was my question

Comment: In **Xamarin.ios** can use UIButton,because using UIKit.In **Xamarin.Forms** can not do this. UIKit can not be used.Froms is a cross-platform,when it be designed,it can not directly do that,must by render,so that other platform is also a way to achieve cross-platform results.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't make sense to me